# How to access the superclass

Tags: ruby

With the code below, I want to print the statement, then add the subclass created into `@animals` array every time a new subclass is created. I'd like to know how I can create an instance of `Animal` and use its variable `@animals`.

```
class Animal
  attr_accessor :animals
  def initialize
    @animals = []
  end
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    puts "a new subclass of #{subclass} was created"
    Animal.animals << subclass
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
end

class Cat < Animal
end

dog = Dog.new
cat = Cat.new
```

Comment: Did you write this code, or does it originate from a tutorial somewhere? The `inherited` method makes use of a _class variable_ `Animal.animals` rather than an _instance variable_ `Animal.new.animals`, which you defined in the initializer.

Comment: Is your intent to maintain an array of instantiated subclasses for the whole `Animal` class?

Comment: Yes, I would like to maintain an array of the instantiated subclasses. I want to be able to use metaprogramming and add a subclass to the array each time that one is created.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how I can even access this array! thx in advance, i'm kind of confused on this topic

Comment: _add a subclass to the array each time that one is created_ ... That's a little ambiguous. Do you want to keep an array of all subclass objects that are instantiated, or keep an array merely of the subclasses which are defined to inherit `Animal`? The former would list 2 dogs and 1 cat if you instantiated them as such, while the latter would always just have 2 elements `Dog, Cat` regardless of whether either was ever instantiated.

Comment: I would like to keep an array of all subclass objects that are substantiated. So I would just like an array that = [<dog1>, <dog2>, <cat1>]. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Animal
  class << self
    attr_reader :animals, :animal_classes
  end
  @animals = []
  @animal_classes = []

  def initialize
    Animal.animals << self
  end

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    Animal.animal_classes << subclass
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
end

class Cat < Animal
end

class Armadillo < Animal
end

dog = Dog.new
cat1 = Cat.new
cat2 = Cat.new

puts "Animals: #{Animal.animals.inspect}"
# => Animals: [#<Dog:0x007ffe6d0acaf8>, #<Cat:0x007ffe6d0acaa8>, #<Cat:0x007ffe6d0aca58>]
puts "Animal Classes: #{Animal.animal_classes.inspect}"
# => Animal Classes: [Dog, Cat, Armadillo]
```

Comment: Thanks, that answered how to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Use a class variable:

```
class Animal
  @@animals = []
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    @@animals << subclass
  end
end
```

... if I understand what you're trying to do.